# How to fix expected an indented block in Login page

Tags: python, python-3.x

Im trying to code a login page, Visual Studio said that line 5 has `IndentationError: expected an indented block`
What can i do to fix this function?
Can I code the login page like this

This just for my practice, im a new coder.

```py
def register_acc(x,y,z):
    while True:
    x = input("Enter nickname: \t")
    if x.isalnum == True:
        while True:
        y = char(input("enter pass:    \t"))
        z = char(input("re enter pass:\t"))
        if y==z:
            Bien=[x,y,z]
            print("Successful create acc:")
            print("Login name:", Bien[0])
            Print("Pass: " , Bien[1])
        else:
            break
    else:
        break
register_acc(x,y,z)
```

Error:

```
File "d:\visual studio ide\common7\ide\extensions\microsoft\python\core\Packages\ptvsd\_vendored\pydevd\_pydev_imps\_pydev_execfile.py", line 25, in execfile
    exec(compile(contents+"\n", file, 'exec'), glob, loc)
  File "C:\Users\APC\source\repos\PythonApplication3\PythonApplication3\PythonApplication3.py", line 5
    x = input("Enter nickname: \t")
    ^
IndentationError: expected an indented block
Press any key to continue . . .
```

Comment: You need to indent the `while True` block starting with `y = ...`. Incidentally, `while True` is generally bad practice.

Comment: After `while True:` you should indent everything you want in your loop

Comment: Also, for password entry consider using https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/getpass.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error is telling you exactly what is wrong, you have forgotten to indent your `while` blocks. They should indent in exactly the same way that the function `def`inition and the `if` statements do.

So:

```
def register_acc(x,y,z):
    while True:
    x = input("Enter nickname: \t")
    if x.isalnum == True:
        while True:
        y = char(input("enter pass:    \t"))
```

should be

```
def register_acc(x,y,z):
    while True:
        x = input("Enter nickname: \t")
        if x.isalnum == True:
            while True:
                y = char(input("enter pass:    \t"))
```

---

A couple of other hints:

- `if x == True:` can be simplified to `if x:`
- Function names are case sensitive, so `Print()` is different to `print()`

If you are just starting out in Python then good luck, I hope you find it as rewarding as I did! There are some great resources out there, but for [teaching how to read error messages I love the Software Carpentry tutorials](https://swcarpentry.github.io/python-novice-inflammation/07-errors/).